# Workaround for using BETWEEN and a WILDCARD

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a fairly large table which contains ICD10 codes (`icd10_table`). I want to pull a bunch of different ICD10 codes (`code`) based on ranges. In short, there are parent ICD10 codes that have "children" that can be pretty expansive. For instance:
ICD10 'M04' can include 'M041', 'M045', 'M04679', 'M04000', 'M04999' and so forth. There really isn't a pattern here and it's very time-consuming to look up and figure out every single combination. Under normal circumstances a simple query with a wildcard like this would pull everything I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM icd10_table
WHERE code LIKE 'M04%'
```

However, I'm trying to pull ranges of specific ICD10 codes and was trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM icd10_table
WHERE code BETWEEN 'M00' AND 'M02%'
OR code BETWEEN 'M04' AND 'M04%'
OR code BETWEEN 'M05' AND 'M14%'
OR code BETWEEN 'M15' AND 'M19%'
```

But this just cuts off the child ICD10's and doesn't actually apply the wildcard. What is a good workaround for using BETWEEN and a wildcard to pull every parent/child ICD10 in range?

Comment: Can you just use `>= 'M00' AND < 'M03'?

Comment: You can only use wildcards in a `like` clause.  There's no easy answer here, sadly enough.  You'll have to build multiple >= and < clauses, as @svenhalvorson suggests/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM icd10_table
WHERE code >= 'M00' AND code < 'M02' OR
      code >= 'M04' AND code < 'M05' OR
      code >= 'M05' AND code < 'M15' OR
      code >= 'M15' AND code < 'M20'
```

Your formulation has `'%'` whose ASCII value is less than any digit, so it effectively cuts off the comparison.